# Macbook Pro Retina 13 Crashes frequently

Tags: macbook-pro, crash

I have a Macbook Pro Retina 13 from 2015 that is crashing very often lately.

Please, help me on some directions to do.

This is the crash log:

```
Anonymous UUID:       22DF2EC5-67E3-0E1E-A370-D15FEB555221

    Tue Mar  1 14:34:09 2016

    *** Panic Report ***
    Machine-check capabilities: 0x0000000001000c07
    family: 6 model: 61 stepping: 4 microcode: 33
    signature: 0x306d4
    Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5557U CPU @ 3.10GHz
    7 error-reporting banks
    Processor 0: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000005
    IA32_MC0_STATUS(0x401): 0xb200000000090005
    Processor 1: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000005
    IA32_MC0_STATUS(0x401): 0xb200000000090005
    panic(cpu 1 caller 0xffffff800bfd301a): "Machine Check at 0xffffff800bff0d81, registers:\n" "CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x00001d5082e49000, CR3: 0x000000000f132000, CR4: 0x00000000003627e0\n" "RAX: 0x0000000000000060, RBX: 0x07fffffffffffd92, RCX: 0x0000000000000001, RDX: 0x0000000000000000\n" "RSP: 0xffffff91f7013ee0, RBP: 0xffffff91f7013f20, RSI: 0x0000000000000002, RDI: 0xffffff800c6f7d40\n" "R8:  0x0000000000000004, R9:  0x0000000000000000, R10: 0x0000000000000000, R11: 0x0000000000000001\n" "R12: 0x0000000000000060, R13: 0x0000000000000380, R14: 0xffffff800c6f8100, R15: 0x0000000000000000\n" "RFL: 0x0000000000000046, RIP: 0xffffff800bff0d81, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010\n" "Error code: 0x0000000000000000\n"@/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-3248.30.4/osfmk/i386/trap_native.c:168
    Backtrace (CPU 1), Frame : Return Address
    0xffffff81ead35e90 : 0xffffff800bedf792
    0xffffff81ead35f10 : 0xffffff800bfd301a
    0xffffff81ead36070 : 0xffffff800bff0acf
    0xffffff91f7013f20 : 0xffffff800bfd42b9
    0xffffff91f7013f40 : 0xffffff800bef6cfd
    0xffffff91f7013f90 : 0xffffff800bef71f0
    0xffffff91f7013fb0 : 0xffffff800bfccf77

    BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

    Mac OS version:
    15D21

    Kernel version:
    Darwin Kernel Version 15.3.0: Thu Dec 10 18:40:58 PST 2015; root:xnu-3248.30.4~1/RELEASE_X86_64
    Kernel UUID: DECC9F02-27D7-31F0-9599-A9EF2873902C
    Kernel slide:     0x000000000bc00000
    Kernel text base: 0xffffff800be00000
    __HIB  text base: 0xffffff800bd00000
    System model name: MacBookPro12,1 (Mac-E43C1C25D4880AD6)

    System uptime in nanoseconds: 422025213538
    last loaded kext at 368780524837: com.apple.filesystems.smbfs   3.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7f8e9d3000, size 409600)
    last unloaded kext at 105379511467: com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssI2C  2.0.59 (addr 0xffffff7f8e26e000, size 36864)
    loaded kexts:
    org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  5.0.10
    org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  5.0.10
    org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 5.0.10
    org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 5.0.10
    com.intel.kext.intelhaxm    1.1.5
    com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 3.0.0
    com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
    com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
    com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.20.22
    com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
    com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.6.0d0
    com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy  3.7.7
    com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
    com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
    com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   272.51.3
    com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
    com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
    com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.4.3f4
    com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
    com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
    com.apple.driver.AppleIntelBDWGraphics  10.1.2
    com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
    com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
    com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.4.3f4
    com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    208
    com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.0.8
    com.apple.driver.AppleIntelBDWGraphicsFramebuffer   10.1.2
    com.apple.driver.AppleCameraInterface   5.41.0
    com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.8.8
    com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.13
    com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.7.1
    com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
    com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
    com.apple.BootCache 38
    com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.8.5
    com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.8
    com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver 86
    com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   1020.17.1a1
    com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
    com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
    com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   4.0
    com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
    com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
    com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    4.0
    com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
    com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   163
    com.apple.security.quarantine   3
    com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
    com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 900.4.1
    com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
    com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 272.51.3
    com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    525
    com.apple.driver.CoreCaptureResponder   1
    com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   108.0.1
    com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 272.51.3
    com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 272.51.3
    com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   204.3
    com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
    com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
    com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.4.3f4
    com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.4.3f4
    com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
    com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.12.6
    com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    205.1
    com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
    com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d7
    com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.12.6
    com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
    com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
    com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
    com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.14d1
    com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
    com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.7.7
    com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  1.0.0
    com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.7
    com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    517.20.1
    com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.8.1
    com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.1.3
    com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.1.3
    com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
    com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   181
    com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  304.10
    com.apple.driver.AppleHIDTransport  5
    com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPIHIDDriver    41.7
    com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.0.4
    com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 5.1.0
    com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1110.26
    com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
    com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
    com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
    com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPISupport  41.7
    com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssSpiController    2.0.59
    com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssGspi 2.0.59
    com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssDmac 2.0.59
    com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.0.1
    com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.0.1
    com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
    com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.0.1
    com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.0.1
    com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
    com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
    com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
    com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
    com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
    com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
    com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
    com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
    com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
    com.apple.driver.DiskImages 417.2
    com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
    com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
    com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
    com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  4.0
    com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
    com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
    com.apple.kec.Libm  1
    com.apple.kec.pthread   1
    com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
    Model: MacBookPro12,1, BootROM MBP121.0167.B15, 2 processors, Intel Core i7, 3,1 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.28f7
    Graphics: Intel Iris Graphics 6100, Intel Iris Graphics 6100, Built-In
    Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1867 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x483943434E4E4E434C544D4C41522D4E5544
    Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1867 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x483943434E4E4E434C544D4C41522D4E5544
    AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x133), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.94.136.1a1)
    Bluetooth: Version 4.4.3f4 16616, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
    Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
    Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0256G, 251 GB
    USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
    USB Device: Card Reader
    USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
    Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 27.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually a symptom of:

- bad memory (run apple hardware test, it will tell you)
- bad kext (try removing 3rd party software one by one, start with virtualbox)
- problems with motherboard (again, apple hardware test)

Here is how to run Apple Hardware Test: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've run the Apple Diagnostics and it seems that there are no issues. With that response I can discard hardware problems (memory, motherboard) ?

Comment: It does not exclude hardware problem for 100% but it is a significant chance that you do not have them. For example, I had a problem with memory, which only happened when the computer was very hot. So running hardware test did not help me first but after I ran it repeatedly for several hours, it started to report memory failures. I went to apple service to replace the memory.